# prevent box-shadow on child element

Tags: html, css

I have some div elements and I want to assign `box-shadow` attribute when hover on them.

```
<style>
    .hover-item :hover {
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px;

    }

</style>
```

But when i assign this class to them , their children `<img />` and `<h1></h1>` get this attribute and when I hover them they will have shadow. 
I cant assign id to div elements because of some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only wanting to add the shadow to the .hover-item, you need to take out the space, like this: `.hover-item:hover`. With the space (like you have it), CSS is interpreting it as you saying look inside `.hover-item` and find every `:hover` child element

Comment: It works.thank you.